# Facebook crawler don't show content of meta tags

Tags: php, html, facebook, laravel, meta

Hi I'm having problems with the facebook share option in the meta tags of my website.

I'm using laravel to fill the contents with the blade syntax

```
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ $domain }}"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Rapsodia Invierno 15"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ $seo[0]['description'] }}"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/img.jpg"/>
```

And in fact when I open the chrome debugger it show me the text of the variables

(I can upload images so, here it is written)

```
<!-- SEO Shares -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="Bienvenido a Rapsodia -  Rapsodia.com">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <!-- <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.rapsodia.com/ar"/> -->
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Rapsodia Invierno 15">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Descubrí el Universo Rapsodia y su última colección Inv15 inspirada en diferentes culturas y décadas, en el arte, en la música y viajes por el mundo.">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/img.jpg">
```

Comment: You've got some sort of a redirect that's causing both the [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rapsodia.com%2Far) and [W3C](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rapsodia.com%2Far&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) parsers to fail.

Comment: What do you mean? would you explain me a little?

Comment: Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ and debug. It say that you are not returning anything to Facebook

Comment: Facebook retrieve me no data from the debugger on the scrapped url option and give me a redirect 302 to the same page. Can I add an exception in my .htaccess file? so facebook dont have to look the og tags in a redirect page

Comment: `http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/` first redirects to `http://www.rapsodia.com/`, and then that redirects back to `http://www.rapsodia.com/ar/`. Since cookies are being set in the process, I assume there is some reasoning behind this – but it breaks in clients that don’t accept cookies. So _that_ is the problem that you should fix.